# CSV to database with php

Tags: php, csv, ms-access, fgetcsv

I have a little issue with importing data from .csv file to "ms access" database.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="csv"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
        </form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $i=0;
            require "connection.php";
            if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'])) {
                echo "<h3>" . "File ". $_FILES['csv']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h3>";
            }
            //Import uploaded file to Database
            $handle = fopen($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'], "r");
            $import=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO adherence(
                    dateandtime,
                    lastname,
                    paidtime,
                    approvedtime,
                    notadhering) VALUES(
                    ?,?,?,?,?)");
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t", "'")) !== FALSE) {
                if($i>0) {
                $data = str_replace('"', '', $data);
                $myDate =  date("Y/m/d",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$data[0])));
                $import->bindParam(1, $myDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->bindParam(2, $data[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->bindParam(3, $data[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->bindParam(4, $data[3], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->bindParam(5, $data[4], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->execute();
                }
                $i++;

            }
            /*$removal=$db->prepare("delete FROM adherence WHERE approvedtime = '0' OR notadhering IS NULL");
            $removal->execute();*/

            fclose($handle);
            echo 'IMPORTED' ;
        }
```

**CSV file:**

[image: CSV file]

**Import result:**
[image: database]

I have no clue, why my file is not being imported, and what is this random date. Please assist!

**EDIT:**
[image: Edit]

**Var_dump:**
[image: vardump]

**EDIT 2**

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="csv"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
        </form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $i=0;
            require "connection.php";
            if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'])) {
                echo "<h3>" . "File ". $_FILES['csv']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h3>";
            }
            //Import uploaded file to Database
            $handle = fopen($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'], "r");
            $import=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO adherence(
                    dateandtime,
                    lastname,
                    paidtime,
                    approvedtime,
                    notadhering) VALUES(
                    ?,?,?,?,?)");
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t", "'")) !== FALSE) {
                if($i>0) {
                $data = str_replace('"', '', $data);
                $myDate = date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime($data[0]));
                $import->bindParam(1, $myDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->bindParam(2, $data[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->bindParam(3, $data[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->bindParam(4, $data[3], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->bindParam(5, $data[4], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->execute();
                var_dump($data);
                }
                $i++;

            }
            /*$removal=$db->prepare("delete FROM adherence WHERE approvedtime = '0' OR notadhering IS NULL");
            $removal->execute();*/

            fclose($handle);
            echo 'IMPORTED' ;
        }
```

**EDIT 3**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $i=0;
            require "connection.php";
            if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'])) {
                echo "<h3>" . "File ". $_FILES['csv']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h3>";
            }
            //Import uploaded file to Database
            $handle = fopen($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'], "r");
            $import=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO adherence(
  dateandtime,
  lastname,
  paidtime,
  approvedtime,
  notadhering)
  VALUES(:dateandtime, :lastname, :paidtime, :approvedtime, :notadhering)");
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t", "'")) !== FALSE) {
                if($i>0) {
                $myDate = date("Y/m/d",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$data[0])));   
                $import->execute(array(':dateandtime'=> $myDate, ':lastname'=> $data[1], ':paidtime'=> $data[2], ':approvedtime'=> $data[3], ':notadhering'=> $data[4]));
                }
                $i++;

            }
            /*$removal=$db->prepare("delete FROM adherence WHERE approvedtime = '0' OR notadhering IS NULL");
            $removal->execute();*/

            fclose($handle);
            echo 'IMPORTED' ;
        }
```

**EDIT 4** **FULL CODE**

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="csv"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
        </form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $i=0;
            require "connection.php";
            if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'])) {
                echo "<h3>" . "File ". $_FILES['csv']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h3>";
            }
            //Import uploaded file to Database
            $handle = fopen($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'], "r");
            try {
      $import= $db->prepare("INSERT INTO adherence(
                              dateandtime,
                              lastname,
                              paidtime,
                              approvedtime,
                              notadhering) VALUES(
                              ?,?,?,?,?)");

    $i = 0;        
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        if($i > 0) {
            $data = str_replace('"', '', $data); 

            $import->bindParam(1, $data[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);                
            $import->bindParam(2, $data[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);                
            $import->bindParam(3, $data[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);                
            $import->bindParam(4, $data[3], PDO::PARAM_STR);                
            $import->bindParam(5, $data[4], PDO::PARAM_STR);                
            $import->execute();
        }
        $i++;

    }
}

catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
}}
```

Connection is working. It is .MDB

Comment: Your CSV file's datetime doesn't match MySQL's `datetime` YYYY-mm-dd 00:00:00 format.

Comment: Any tip how to change it?

Comment: Hard to say but you can try changing `$myDate =  date("Y/m/d",strtotime` to `$myDate =  date("d/m/Y",strtotime` see if that fixes it.

Comment: also make sure that the column it is going into, is `datetime` type.

Comment: Not working. Same issue

Comment: I see your csv is missing another set of `:00`. can you work with a test `.csv` copy and modify those to read as `01/04/2015 00:00:00` and see what it does. Or `2015/01/04 00:00:00`

Comment: Can't change csv. It has to be same format as it is now

Comment: ok but can you at least try it. If that fixes it, you'll know what to fix.

Comment: or see if by adding on `:00` will work. I have a doubt, but worth a shot `$myDate =  date("Y/m/d",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$data[0]))) . " :00";`

Comment: It gives fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[22018]: Invalid character value for cast specification: -3030 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSERT into DB DateTime string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539154/insert-into-db-datetime-string)

Comment: Switch to `Y-m-d` in your call to `date()`

Comment: Same problem. No INSERT duplicates.

Comment: Use this for myDate: `$myDate =  date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime($data[0]));` If that doesn't work: Do `var_dump($data);` just inside the while loop and edit the question with that output

Comment: added result in Edit

Comment: That "random date" means you're passing 0 as the second parameter to the date function. Show your updated code

Comment: With pdo, you can use named placeholders instead of just `?`. Try those? So your query is `INSERT INTO... VALUES (:theDate, :lastName, :paidTime, :approvedTime, :notadhering)` Then remove all the bindParam's and use `$import->execute(array(':theDate'=> $myDate, ':lastName'=> $data[0],...` and so on instead

Comment: @Terminus code (EDIT 3) gives errors:
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 
Notice: Undefined offset: 3
Notice: Undefined offset: 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fundamental issue is you do not specify the comma delimiter in the `fgetcsv()` function. As a result, all the data pushed into one column, `date[0]` and the Access ACE/JET engine unable to convert to date/time of the first column rendered all to zero which in [unix time begins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090869/why-is-1-1-1970-the-epoch-time) at 1/1/1970.

Also, consider using `try/catch` to catch PDO exceptions.

```
try {
      $import= $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO adherence(
                              dateandtime,
                              lastname,
                              paidtime,
                              approvedtime,
                              notadhering) VALUES(
                              ?,?,?,?,?)");

    $i = 0;        
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        if($i > 0) {
            $data = str_replace('"', '', $data); 

            $import->bindParam(1, $data[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);                
            $import->bindParam(2, $data[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);                
            $import->bindParam(3, $data[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);                
            $import->bindParam(4, $data[3], PDO::PARAM_STR);                
            $import->bindParam(5, $data[4], PDO::PARAM_STR);                
            $import->execute();
        }
        $i++;

    }
}

catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
}
```

As for dates, MS Access date/time field follows the current CPU's language clock such as `MM/DD/YYYY` (US) or `DD/MM/YYYY` (UK), etc. It does not follow the date/time format of other RDMS's of `YYYY-MM-DD` or such variants. So there is no need to convert since your csv aligned already to Access' format. With that being said, you may receive a warning:

```
SQLSTATE[22018]: Invalid character value for cast specification: -3030
```

However, according to my tests, the database updated all rows correctly. Normally, you would concatenate the `#` around date strings which I tried to no avail with your code but possibly in your bind parameters process, string types do not wrap ideally with the hashtags.

Comment: Yes, I get error: SQLSTATE[22018]: Invalid character value for cast specification: -3030. still -same failure

Comment: Did you check database results? As mentioned from testing if you changed delimiter, csv records still append. This may be a PDO exception caught in `try/catch` not a PHP fatal error. Alternatively, make dateandtime a string variable and update it to another date/time field with `#` or [CDate()](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/datatype/cdate.php) after insert.

Comment: Not importing a thing

Comment: Interesting. Code works here. If you comment out the PDO catch line, `SQLSTATE[22018]:` message does not appear. Did you refresh the Access table? Did you change the `fgetcsv()` arguments? Notice I remove the `\t` and `'` for comma `,`. If yes to all above, can you edit your post to add the PDO connection string to see driver/dsn and file type (.mdb or .accdb)?